# how to get the categories for a single post in a hierarchical way

Tags: categories, hierarchical

The question is simple.
Imagine that I have a post named 'Single Post' which is inside the category 'sub-cat' which is a child of 'parent-cat' which is a child of 'super-cat'.
What I need to do is to display all the related categories within the post page in the following order:

```
super-cat > parent-cat > sub-cat > Single Post
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php 
    the_category( ' > ', 'multiple', $post->ID); 
    echo ' > ';
    the_title();
?>
```

This works correctly when the post is in just one category. But if it's in multiple categories, or if the category parents are also selected — in your case, if the post is also in super-cat and parent-cat — then it displays those categories twice.
So this is probably not going to do it for you.

I suspect some of the [breadcrumb type plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=breadcrumb) might have solved this though.

Comment: In case there are several categories per post, you need to find the "final" ones (sub-cat's) and then get their parents one by one.

Answer (score 2):

you need to sort the categories first.

```
// get categories of post in sorted order
$categories = sortCategories(get_the_category());     

foreach($categories AS $category) {
    echo $category->name; // Plot category name
}
echo get_the_title(); // Plot post name

function sortCategories($categories) { // Sorting the category
    usort($categories, "cmpCategories");
    return $categories;
}

function cmpCategories($category_1,$category_2) { // Sort function
    foreach(get_categories(array("parent" => $category_1->cat_ID)) AS $sub) {
        if($category_2->cat_ID == $sub->cat_ID) return -1;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$cats = get_the_category(); //retrieve cats for post

foreach ($cats as $cat) { //go thru to find child one - means cat which has specified parent id
    if ($cat->category_parent != 0) {
        $child = $cat->term_taxonomy_id;
    }
}
echo get_category_parents( $child, TRUE, ' > ' );
```

First we get categories for particular post, then we find last child and then with get_category_parents we get whole tree of its parents...

Comment: doesn't work...

Comment: this assumes that there is only one subcategory to each parent. in case there are more children and sub-children, this breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Here my working solution for that:

```
$categories = get_the_category();

$ordering = array();
foreach( $categories as $index => $cat) {
    $ordering[$cat->parent] = $index;
}

$ordered_string = "";
$i = 0;
while( $ordering[$i] !== null ){
    $ordered_string .= '<li class="item-cat"><a href="'.get_category_link( $categories[$ordering[$i]]->term_id ).'">'.$categories[$ordering[$i]]->name.'</li>';

    $i = $categories[$ordering[$i]]->term_id;
}

echo $ordered_string;
```

It echoes the string ready for the breadcrumb, and with a little modification yo can get the categories ordered as array.

Comment: this works, but only if there just one top-level category. If the post is in several hierarchical categories, one will overwrite the other

Answer (score 1):

Old question but top result on Google for me.  I couldn't quickly find a breadcrumb categorization, supporting multiple categories, so I created one and wrapped it in a `ul` for easy styling:

```
// breadcrumb categorization
$cats = wp_get_post_categories( get_the_ID() );  //post id
foreach($cats as $c) {
    $ancestors = array_merge( array_reverse( get_ancestors( $c, 'category' ) ), [$c] );
    echo '<ul class="post-categories">';
    foreach($ancestors as $id){
        echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $id) ) . '">' . get_cat_name( $id ) . '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```